# Local scope in Dir.foreach() Ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, global-variables

Why is the scope of a variable in a Dir.foreach loop local?

I was looping through files until I found the info I needed from a file and set it equal to a variable, but outside the loop the variable couldn't be seen. I'm using a global variable for now, but as that's not favored in Ruby, I'd like not to have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

when you set a variable in a block, unless there's a previously defined variable in the outer scope it won't be available from the outer scope.

"global" just means outermost scope. There are two main levels of scoping - method and block.  In either case you'll see the same behavior.

```
a = 0
def foo
  a = 1
  b = 2
end
foo
a # => 1
b # => NameError

1.times do
  a = 2
  b = 3  
end
a # => 2
b # => NameError
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised I never ran into that before. Hope it's a lesson learned. Guess I don't use blocks this way very often or have declared the variable for some other reason. Now my global variable is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need one element use `find`

```
fname = Dir.foreach('.').find { |each| each =~ /store/i }
```

Otherwise what Maxple said, when you define a variable inside a block it is defined in the scope of that block only but not outside. You must define the variable before the block if you want to use it both inside and outside.

But as mentioned, you can almost always use a function on `Enumerable` module instead. Useful ones are `select` and `find` and `map` and `any?`, best read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. That's why they are called "local" variables, after all.

There are four local variable scopes in Ruby: script, module/class definition, method, and block/λ-literal. Of these four, only block scopes nest, and only blocks can be closures.

So, if you define a local variable in a block, it is local to that block. If, however, you define a local variable *outside* a block, then it will be available in the block (unless explicitly declared as a block local variable), because the block scope nests inside the outer scope. It will even be available in the block after the outer scope ends, because block scopes close over their surrounding lexical environment.

Note: even though `for`/`in` iterators desugar into a message to `each` with a block, in this *special* case, the block does not get its own scope. One more reason to avoid `for`/`in`.

```
foo = :outerfoo
bar = :outerbar

[nil].each do |*; bar|
  foo = :innerfoo
  bar = :innerbar
  baz = :innerbaz
end

foo #=> :innerfoo
bar #=> :outerbar
baz # NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object

for * in [nil]
  looks_local_but_isnt = :huh
end

looks_local_but_isnt #=> :huh
```